# How to get a dependency list out of webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Webpack takes a long time to run, so it'd be nice to not run it when not necessary.  Is there a way to generate a list of dependencies, like `gcc -M` does?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first attempt.   There must be a better way:

```
webpack --json | 
jq -r '.chunks[0].modules[].name' | 
sed "s|/~/|/node_modules/|g" | 
grep -v "^multi " | # filter out entries
grep -v "(" | # filter out (ignored) and (webpack)/buildin etc
sed 's/.*!//' | # ignore the loaders
```